# How can fetch ProductIDs in Apple Connect?(In App Purchase)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, applet

I'm trying to do fetch ProductIDs. But response always be null. 
I want to show what I do.

1. I Create App IDs in developer Account.[BundleID equal to AppID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6o3u.png)
2. I've installed the project App Connect. Selected my Project BundleID
3. [Created ProductID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acUm.png)
4. Switch on the [In App Purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMgJc.png) in Xcode
5. My Code:

> Created ProductID's:

```
             `enum IAPProduct: String {
                case Consumble = "com.xxxx.xxx.Consumable"
                case nonConsumble = "com.xxxx.xxx.TekSeferAl"
                       }`
```

> My fetch code:

```
 class IAPService: NSObject {
static let shared = IAPService()
private override init() {}

//MARK:- Properties
//MARK:- Private

func getProducts() {
    SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    let products: Set = [IAPProduct.Consumble.rawValue,
                         IAPProduct.nonConsumble.rawValue]
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
    request.cancel()
    request.delegate  = self
    request.start()

   }
}
```

> Delegate:

```
 extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    response.invalidProductIdentifiers.forEach { product in
        print("Invalid: \(product)")
    }

    response.products.forEach { product in
        print("Valid: \(product)")

    }
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error for request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

> Output

[image]

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: please make sure you bundle id on iTunes connect the same with you app bundle id

Comment: and check the contract for paid applications is valid and bank info . https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/203122052-Create-an-Apple-App-Store-Paid-Applications-Contract

Comment: [https://imgur.com/xA4dmQa] looking problem 2nd.

Comment: ok, you must to set up contract and tax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it seems your products are in the state of "Missing Metadata" in App Store Connect - they need to be in "Ready to Submit" for testing.

You're probably either:

1. Missing a photo (you can use a blank image for testing)
2. Haven't signed the the Paid Applications Agreement with Apple

Here's a good blog post that covers setting up products in more detail: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)